# Magnetic ion drive

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, propulsion

One of the problems of ion drives is that the electrode is corroded by impacts from the ions we are accelerating. Instead of an electric potential, could we use a magnetic field to accelerate the ions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magnetic fields do not speed up charged particles; they only deflect them. This is because the magnetic force on a charged particle is perpendicular to its velocity and thus does no work on the particle.

Comment: Would the same be true of varying magnetic fields? Also, maglev trains use magnetism to accelerate don't they?

Comment: @Bingohank A time-varying magnetic field does not speed up charged particles. However, a time-varying magnetic field causes an electric field, which can speed them up. Maglev trains do not work by having a magnetic field speed up charged particles.

Comment: G.Smith thank you for your answer. So a time varying magnetic field causes an electric field which can speed them up. Can't we therefore use this to eliminate the need for electrodes?

Comment: That seems problematic. You can’t increase a magnetic field indefinitely. You’d have to use an oscillating one. That would make the electric field oscillate as well, so you would periodically be accelerating the ions in the opposite direction.

Comment: Could you introduce an inverter to keep the ions accelerating in the same direction?